# keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist; for Unity Firebase integration

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, keystore, keytool

I have already seen similar questions on here. I cannot execute this command eventhough I have installes Java as well as Android Studio and added "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_321\bin" to my path and also the "debug.keystore" actually is at the following path "C:\Users\rxcov.android" so what could possibly still cause this issue? I would be really grateful for some help!

```
C:\Users\rxcov>keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore rxcov\.android\debug.keystore
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: rxcov\.android\debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: rxcov\.android\debug.keystore
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: the path you mentioned ("C:\Users\rxcov.android") is no the path you are executing your command with.